# SQL query in Crystal Reports doesn't update

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I'm writing an application which changes **Crystal Reports** database access parameters in report files. I open reports witin a **.NET windows forms app** and apply the SDK functionality to change driver type (ODBC/OLEDB), server name, database name, user, password, authentication type etc. I'm having a **problem with the database name**. My code DOES change the specific properties of the table ConnectionInfo (in subreports too) but **fails to update the general SQL Query** within the report. This results in the report still accessing the old database.

So if the original report was configured to access database_1 and I'm changing it to database_2, it will have all table properties properly changed to database_2 (verifiable in the Designer). It will still have database_1 in the query though. The database name remains unchanged in both the SDK RowsetController.GetSQLStatement() result and in the Crystal Reports Developer query view (Database->Show SQL Query...).

Also **I have to have both databases (database_1 and database_2) online** while the conversion takes place, otherwise I get exceptions on either GetSQLStatement(when database_1 is offline; becuase it still refers to it) or SetTableLocation (when database_2 is offline - this is expected and acceptable behavior though). If both db are online, there are no errors.

**Here is exactly what I'm using:**

1) CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(filePath, OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy)
(...)

2) Make and fill CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag

3) Iterate through CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.Tables and apply all properties with SetTableLocaiton() for each one.

4) Repeat with each subreport

5) RowsetController.GetSQLStatement() to view the report's sql query.

Is there some way to update the query basing on the new table ConnectionInfos (which seem to be set properly)? I don't even see any possibility of manually updating the query (GET, search&replace, SET).

I'm using:

.NET 4.5, 
Visual Studio 2012, 
CR for VS 13.0.5, 
Crystal Reports Developer 9.2.2.693 for results verification (source reports are also created with it)

Comment: When you say query, do you mean the SQL created by Crystal report or you are using a command and you question is how to update the command ? You may check this product :http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/CRDataSource.aspx If it is able to change the connection you should be able to do this too. Otherwise there is something specific with the query.

Comment: What I meant was the overall SQL query for the main report created by CR. Commands are easily updated while iterating over all tables, applying property bags and using SetTableLocation. I found the answer already, but still, thanks for the link to the product!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: set propper **QualifiedName** for each table. The QualifiedName is the full name of the table including the DbName. This later appears in the SQL Query of the report. By qualified name we understand:

myDatabase.mySchema.myTableName

**Code example:**

```
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.Table boTable = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.Table();
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag boMainPropertyBag = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag();
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag boInnerPropertyBag = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag();

// Custom function to fill property bags with values which influence the table properties as seen in CR Developer
FillPropertyBags(boMainPropertyBag, boInnerPropertyBag);

CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ConnectionInfo boConnectionInfo = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ConnectionInfo();
boConnectionInfo.Attributes = boMainPropertyBag;
boConnectionInfo.Kind = CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.CrConnectionInfoKindEnum.crConnectionInfoKindCRQE;

boTable.ConnectionInfo = boConnectionInfo;

CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.Tables boTables = boReportDocument.ReportClientDocument.DatabaseController.Database.Tables;

for (int i = 0; i < boTables.Count; i++)
{
   boTable.Name = boTables[i].Name;
   // the QualifiedName is directly taken into the CR general query so this is a quick fix to change it
   boTable.QualifiedName = boTables[i].QualifiedName.Replace("oldDbName", "newDbName"); 
   boTable.Alias = boTables[i].Alias;
   boReportDocument.ReportClientDocument.DatabaseController.SetTableLocation(boTables[i], boTable);
}
```

Uhh...Researching for whole day and found answer after publishing question on SO.